# PC behaves as it's not turned on

Tags: motherboard, bios, amd-ryzen

I bought a new PC, with mother-board [Gigabyte AB350M-DS3H V2](https://www.gigabyte.com/br/Motherboard/GA-AB350M-DS3H-V2-rev-11#kf) and CPU Ryzen 5 3600.

The problem is when I turn the PC on, it behaves as it is turned off. Nothing happens, the fans don't move, no lights shine, really nothing, as if the power was off. I tested the PSU alone and it's working fine.

As the mother-board is new, I'm refusing to think it's broken (although it's my best guess).

The mother-board BIOS, as it comes from factory, doesn't support 3rd generation Ryzen, but the store says it comes with updated BIOS so that it should support the Ryzen 5 3600.

My question is: if the BIOS is NOT updated, can the mother-board cause the PC to behave as described?

Comment: I would be inclined to return the unit. BIOS from the factory will not cause the unit to remain off. But an unsupported CPU could cause this and that appears to be what has happened

Comment: I'm talking to the store and solving the problem, but I got curious about this possiblity, since I tested everything I could (took out and reinserted the CPU, tested the PSU).

Comment: Does the PSU have a switch on it?

Comment: Do you get any beeps?

Comment: If there is indeed power to the board, then beep codes should tell you whats wrong. I'm inclined to think there isn't ANY power to the board whatsoever - ensure your PSU is plugged in and switched on.

Comment: I haven't got any kind of sound or beep. Yes, the PSU has a switch and as I said, I tested it isolatedly and it worked fine. My main doubt is if the PC can behave like I described just because the mother-board doesn't support the CPU.

Comment: Did you test the Power On Switch on your PC front panel? The switch shorts 2 pins on the motherboard to start the PSU. Pin out is shown in motherboard manual. Remove the connector from the pins and try to switch on the PC by shorting the 2 pins using a small metallic screwdriver. Does it start. While the behavior may not be predictable, generally if the CPU is unsupported or Dead then motherboard would in principle power on but do nothing except fans spinning or it may attempt to start for 1 - 2 seconds and shut itself off.

Comment: Continued...It may also be possible that your PSU runs OK without any load as a standalone unit but some defect in it may prevent it from starting when under load of the board/CPU/GPU and so on.